# D3 rangeRoundBands - what does it do?

Tags: d3.js

I'm so sorry to ask this, but i have a pile of D3 v3 code, and I'm in no place to upgrade to v4

Sadly, i don't know what a lot of the code does - and everytime I look for "rangeRoundBands" all i get are people discussing where it went in D3 v4

What do the arguments for rangeRoundBands actually do?

Comment: [d3 v3 API for rangeRoundBands](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md#ordinal_rangeRoundBands).

Answer (score 2):

I found [this amazing page](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/making-bar-chart-in-d3js.html) - so from it i can see there are at least two arguments.

`var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);`

> The rangeRoundBands operator provides the magic that arranges our bars in a graceful way across the x axis. In our example we use it to set the range that our bars will cover (in this case from 0 to the width of the graph) and the amount of padding between the bars (in this case we have selected .05 which equates to approximately (depending on the number of pixels available) 5% of the bar width.